# Antiparallel arrows between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, automata

I am attempting to draw state machines in which two states have input that shifts the current state to each other.

The following representation using bent arrows does not suit my application:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}


\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}

\tikzset{
    ->,
    >=stealth',
    every state/.style={
        thick,
    }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        ->,
        >=stealth',
        node distance=2cm,
        every state/.style={thick}
    ]
    \node[state] (a) {};
    \node[state, right of=a] (b) {};

    \draw
        (a) edge[bend right, below] node{1} (b)
        (b) edge[bend right, above] node{2} (a);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Two states with bent arrows]

I have seen in other posts the following technique of specifying the angle from which the arrow leaves the  node to create straight arrows:

```tex
\draw
    (a.-5) edge[below] node{1} (b.185)
    (b.175) edge[above] node{2} (a.5);
```

[image: Two states with straight arrows with an unexplained third arrowhead]

As you can see, this renders an extra arrowhead for some reason.

Using `\path` to draw  edges instead seems to fix this issue:

```tex
\path (a.-5) edge node [below]{1} (b.185);
\path (b.175) edge node [above]{2} (a.5);
```

[image: Two states with straight arrows]

Ultimately, this how I want it to look. However, for complex automata, I don't want to waste time worrying about the angles and would prefer a solution where I focus on the content rather than it's delivery.

To clarify,
I want to be able to specify two straight distinct edges between two nodes going in opposite directions in a manner that is simple and is not dependent on the use case.

It should be possible to connect two nodes positioned arbitrarily relative to each other with double arrows as depicted, much like the `\edge` command connects two nodes with a single straight line that would pass through the centers of each node (though the double line is offset slightly), stopping at their surfaces.

Does such a method exist?

Comment: Welcome. // Sorry, I don't get your question, and I can only vaguely see your objective. Can you please add a sentence or two to your question for clarification? Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO As I understand it, the OP wants to have lines looking like the third image, but with the simplicity of specifying them in a way similar to `[bend right, above]`, for example one could imagine a syntax of `[top]` vs `[bottom]` would put the top and bottom lines in the right place.

Comment: @AlanMunn, interesting, here's what I assume: the OP could specify polar coordinates, but these will change when nodes aren't connected horizonatlly nad have to be adjusted manually again. // So, two potential interpretations, demanind for clarification in my view ...

Comment: Can you please add a second node or node pair, which is not related horizontally? What kind of drawing and labeling do you expect then? Do nodes have a constant or a variable distance for the state machines you want to present?

Comment: Hi!  Are all your arrows horizontal?  I think I have a solution, but for the time being it only works for horizontal arrows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

I use a decoration `back and forth` to construct the arrows.  As you can see in the figure, the double arrow works in all directions.  The decoration takes two arguments, the two labels.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  back and forth/.style 2 args={
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      lineto code={
        \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) coordinate (I);
        \path (\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (F);
        \draw[->] let
        \p1 = (I.center),
        \p2 = (F.center),
        \n1 = {atan2(\y2 -\y1, \x2 -\x1)},
        \n2 = {\n1 +90}
        in ($(I) +(\n1: 2pt) +(\n2: 3pt)$)
        -- ($(F) +(\n1: -2pt) +(\n2: 3pt)$)
        node[pos=.5, above, scale=.8] {#1};
        \draw[<-] let
        \p1 = (I.center),
        \p2 = (F.center),
        \n1 = {atan2(\y2 -\y1, \x2 -\x1)},
        \n2 = {\n1 -90}
        in ($(I) +(\n1: 2pt) +(\n2: 3pt)$)
        -- ($(F) +(\n1: -2pt) +(\n2: 3pt)$)
        node[pos=.5, below, scale=.8] {#2};
      },
    },
    postaction=decorate
  },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
  \path
  (0, 0) node[state] (a) {}
  (4, 2) node[state] (b) {}
  (0, -2) node[state] (c) {}
  node[state, right of=c] (d) {};

  \path[back and forth={3}{7}] (a) -- (b);
  \path[back and forth={1}{2}] (c) -- (d);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 very nice solution!

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: I like this solution.
One thing that may arise in very dense graphs is the need to adjust the placement of the text nodes on the edges. Does this solution allow for the easy addition of tags such as ```[near end]``` and ```[above]``` for either node seperately?

Comment: It does, but there is a price: you'll have more arguments.  There is an upper limit for this number...  But for what are you asking, the modifications might be lik that: 1) in the declaration, `/.style n args={4}{%`, 2) for the first node `node[pos=#3, above, scale=.8] {#1};`, 3) for the second node `node[pos=#4, above, scale=.8] {#2};`.  The call in the example would become `back and forth={3}{7}{.5}{.5}`.  Note that there is a major problem when an arrow is vertical.  The changes needed to handle that issue are bigger.  If you need something like that, let me know and I'll modify the answer.

Comment: I was finally able to test out this solution.
I found I needed at least two extra parameters and and at most 4,
two each for the positioning and placement along the line respectively for each line.
I appreciate your help very much. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad you can use it.